# Selecting Items with the same subcollection using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Here is the pseudo case:

```
class parent{
   string name; //Some Property
   List<int> myValues;

   .......
}
........
//Initialize some parent classes

List<parent> parentList = new List<parent>();
parentList.add(parent123); //parent123.myValues == {1,2,3}
parentList.add(parent456); //parent456.myValues == {4,5,6}
parentList.add(parentMatch); //parentMatch.myValues == {1,2,3}
```

What I am aiming for is a query which retrieves a List of parent objects where their 
   myValues Lists are equivalent. In this case it would return parent123 and parentMatch.

Comment: @forcripesake: Could you clarify what 'where the myValues List contain the same integers' means?

Comment: Does this means you want to find all the `parent` whose `myValues` match each other? i.e. the List<int> are the same?

Comment: @forcripesake: Btw, if you want the query to work on `List<parent>` without needing to resort to reflection, you will have to expose those fields through public properties (or make the fields themselves public, but this is a bad idea).

Comment: sorry for the poorly worded question, edited for clarity.

Comment: @Ani, the ellipses inside the class was to denote appropriate Accessors and methods. Again, sorry, reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can wrap the logic up and just use `GroupBy` if you implement an `IEqualityComparer`:

```
class IntegerListComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<List<int>> Members

    public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        //bool xContainsY = y.All(i => x.Contains(i));
        //bool yContainsX = x.All(i => y.Contains(i));
        //return xContainsY && yContainsX;
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<int> obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Call it like so:

```
var results = list
    .GroupBy(p => p.MyValues, new IntegerListComparer())
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Comment: +1 I was just writing it in my answer... this is probably the best/right solution.  ;)

Comment: I'm going to try this, how do I return a List<parent> as opposed to the anon type?

Comment: @Zachary: Maybe, you could slightly gain speed by returning obj.Count in GetHashCode, or for example returning first 2-3 elements sum. And, you miss where clause to filter single-occurring parents.

Comment: @forcripesake: first you should add `.Where(x => x.Count() > 1)` to filter parents with unique list, then `.SelectMany(x => x).ToList()` to get a list of all parents with list repeated.

Comment: {3,2,1} == {1,2,3} == {3,3,3,2,2,1} ?

Comment: @digEmAll: this is the second comment, claiming an answer to be right/best. But until know your solution is the only fully working one, and far from be the "best".

Comment: @Nappy I think somewhere the OP said that the lists would be distinct and in the same order.

Comment: @Nappy: you're right, I didn't notice the wrong Contains usage. Anyway, I still think this is the right approach, it has just to be improved, for example with a simple SequenceEquals in the Equals method.

Answer (score 1):

Very silly solution:

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(p => string.Join(",", p.list.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()))
                    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToList();
```

Result:

an `IEnumerable` of groups containing parent objects having list with same int (in the same order).

If you need to match list of elements in any order (i.e. 1,2,3 == 3,1,2), just change `p.list` to `p.list.OrderBy(x => x)`.

Plus, if you're targeting framework 4.0, you can avoid `ToArray` and `ToString`

---

**EDIT:**

added a where to filter single-occurrence groups.

Now if you have these parents:

```
parent  A  1,2,3
parent  B  1,2,3
parent  C  1,2,3
parent  D  4,5,6
parent  E  4,5,6
parent  F  7,8,9
```

it returns:

```
(A,B,C) - (D,E)
```

Comment: This returns the flattened array of ints, some work still then to find the first object whose list matches this flattened value. Also returns those with just 1 entry, not multiples.

Comment: It works fine, I've tested it. It returns groups of parents with same elements.

Comment: +1 @digEmAll: I haven't the time to change my solution  to meet the OP's requirements; it will need more work to make it efficient. This solution is simple; and despite relying on *string* comparisons, it works and that's what's important.

Comment: @Ani: Yes, I was just modifying my solution to use IEqualityComparer to avoid string conversion/comparison, but Zachary anticipated me :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var matches = (from p1 in parentList
               from p2 in parentList
               let c1 = p1.myValues
               let c2 = p2.myValues
               where p1 != p2 &&
                     c1.All(child => c2.Contains(child)) &&
                     c2.All(child => c1.Contains(child))
               select p1).Distinct();
```

Comment: Forgot to mention... this ignores duplicity and order.